# Как составить регулярное выражение с плавающей точкой и ограничением?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как составить регулярное выражение, которое пропускает число с плавающей точкой от -29999984 до 29999983?

у меня уже есть регулярное выражение, которое пропускает число с плавающей точкой:

```
[+-]?([0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)
```

осталось лишь наложить на него ограничения

Я бы хотел видеть такое регулярное выражение, в которое я мог подставить любое минимальное число и любое максимальное

Comment: если например число от нуля до 84 - `^(\d|[0-7]\d|[8[0-4])$` - дальше по аналогии

Comment: splash58, Ваш пример не учитывает плавающую точку

Comment: Он и знака не учитывает. Я хотел показать, что это сильно заморочено

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stanislav Volodarskiy Дал правильное решение.

только чтобы учесть весь диапазон, нужно расширить это

```
def expr():
    return '|'.join(f'(^{s}$)' for s in (
        '[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?'         , #             s < 10000000
        '1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?'          , # 10000000 <= s < 20000000
        '2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?'     , # 20000000 <= s < 29000000
        '29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?'    , # 29000000 <= s < 29900000
        '299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?'   , # 29900000 <= s < 29990000
        '2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?'  , # 29990000 <= s < 29999000
        '29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?' , # 29999000 <= s < 29999900
        '299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?'   , # 29999900 <= s < 29999980
        '2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?'       , # 29999980 <= s < 29999983
        '29999983(\.[0]*)?'             , # 29999983 == s
    ))
```

на это:

```
def expr():
    return '|'.join(f'(^{s}$)' for s in (
        '-[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?' 
        '-1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-2999998[0-3](\.[0-9]*)?',
        '-29999984(\.[0]*)?',
        '[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?'         , #             s < 10000000
        '1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?'          , # 10000000 <= s < 20000000
        '2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?'     , # 20000000 <= s < 29000000
        '29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?'    , # 29000000 <= s < 29900000
        '299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?'   , # 29900000 <= s < 29990000
        '2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?'  , # 29990000 <= s < 29999000
        '29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?' , # 29999000 <= s < 29999900
        '299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?'   , # 29999900 <= s < 29999980
        '2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?'       , # 29999980 <= s < 29999983
        '29999983(\.[0]*)?'             , # 29999983 == s
    ))
```

и конечное регулярное выражение будет следующим:

```
(^-1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-2999998[0-3](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^-29999984(\.[0]*)?$)|(^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^29999983(\.[0]*)?$)
```

Также, предлагаю регулярное выражение с тем же функционалом, но сокращенной записью

```
def expr():
    return '|'.join(f'(^{s}$)' for s in (
        '[+-]?[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+',
        '[+-]?1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+-]?2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+-]?29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+-]?299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+-]?2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+-]?29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+-]?299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?',
        '\-2999998[0-3](\.[0-9]*)?',
        '[+]?2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?',
        '\-29999984(\.[0]*)?',
        '29999983(\.[0]*)?',
    ))
```

и конечное регулярное выражение будет следующим:

```
(^[+-]?[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?|\.[0-9]+$)|(^[+-]?1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+-]?299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^\-2999998[0-3](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^[+]?2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^\-29999984(\.[0]*)?$)|(^29999983(\.[0]*)?$)
```

Comment: `-1` и все короткие отрицательные числа не попали в ответ.

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: Вы когда писали отрицательную часть пропустили одно предложение, которое отвечает за короткие числа. В положительной части десять предложений, в отрицательной только девять. Добавьте недостающее предложение.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что это будет следующая строка: «-[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?»

Comment: Думаю что это она.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярные выражения воспринимают данные как строки, а не как числа, следовательно выполнять логические операции над данными они не могут. Вашу задачу правильнее и легче будет сделать с помощью `if-else`.

С использованием регулярных выражений такое решение сделать либо не получиться вовсе, либо оно будет очень громоздким.

[Здесь есть пример ограничения от 1 до 16](https://qna.habr.com/q/726751), но как там правильно указано данное решение не является масштабируемым.

Answer (score 1):

Баловство это всё. Вот пример регулярного выражения для неотрицательных вещественных чисел с фиксированной запятой в диапазоне [0, 29999983]:

```
import re


def expr():
    return '|'.join(f'(^{s}$)' for s in (
        '[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?'         , #             s < 10000000
        '1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?'          , # 10000000 <= s < 20000000
        '2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?'     , # 20000000 <= s < 29000000
        '29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?'    , # 29000000 <= s < 29900000
        '299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?'   , # 29900000 <= s < 29990000
        '2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?'  , # 29990000 <= s < 29999000
        '29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?' , # 29999000 <= s < 29999900
        '299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?'   , # 29999900 <= s < 29999980
        '2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?'       , # 29999980 <= s < 29999983
        '29999983(\.[0]*)?'             , # 29999983 == s
    ))


def less(s):
    return re.search(expr(), s) is not None


def test(s):
    print(less(s), repr(s))
    assert less(s) == (float(s) <= 29999983)

    
print(expr())
test('0')
test('1')
test('1.0001')
test('9999999')
test('9999999.33')
test('19999999')
test('19999999.33')
test('28999999')
test('28999999.33')
test('29899999')
test('29899999.33')
test('29989999')
test('29989999.33')
test('29998999')
test('29998999.33')
test('29999899')
test('29999899.33')
test('29999979')
test('29999979.33')
test('29999982')
test('29999982.33')
test('29999983')
test('29999983.00')
test('29999983.01')
test('29999984')
test('29999984.01')
test('29999990')
test('29999990.01')
test('30000000')
test('30000000.01')
test('99999999')
test('999999999')
```

Регулярка разбитая по строкам для удобства:

> ```
> (^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?$)|
> (^29999983(\.[0]*)?$)
> ```

Регулярка:

> ```
> (^[0-9]{1,7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^1[0-9]{7}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^2[0-8][0-9]{6}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^29[0-8][0-9]{5}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^299[0-8][0-9]{4}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^2999[0-8][0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^29999[0-8][0-9]{2}(\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^299999[0-7][0-9](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^2999998[0-2](\.[0-9]*)?$)|(^29999983(\.[0]*)?$)
> ```

Отрицательный диапазон строится по аналогии. Нетрудно написать автоматический генератор.

Comment: не совсем понятно как генерировать для отрицательных чисел

Comment: Отрицательное число выглядит также как положительное, только впереди минус. Добавьте ещё десять образцов для обработки отрицательных чисел. Так как диапазоны очень похожи, то часть образцов можно будет объединить.